# For a system of nonlinear equations, is it necessary to have one equation per unknown for uniqueness of solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have a system of nonlinear equations.  Suppose also that I'm interested in knowing if a unique solution exists.  Presumably, a quick check would be to ensure that the number of equations equals the number of unknowns.  If the number of equations is less than the number of unknowns (at least in linear algebra), the solution won't be unique even if it does exist, so there's no point searching for a unique solution.  Is there a similar necessary condition for systems of nonlinear equations?  Put another way, is it possible to create a system of nonlinear equations in $n$ unknowns that contains $m \ne n$ equations for which a unique solution exists?

**EDIT**: As pointed out in an answer, there are examples of trivial solutions such as: $x^2 + y^2 = 0$, in which the only solution is $x = y = 0$.  I am therefore interested in nontrivial solutions.

Comment: A linear system can have more equations than unknowns and a unique solution.

Comment: How do you define trivial? Is $(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2=0$ trivial?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I've edited it to indicate number of equations less than number of unknowns, although I'm starting to suspect that this question isn't precise enough to have a useful answer

Comment: @Théophile: good point.  See my comment above about this question lacking precision

Comment: I think the spirit of the question is clear, and can be addressed. An equation in $n$ variables represents a set in $\Bbb{R}^n$. The number of equations required to pin down solutions depends on the nature of those solution sets. This is what we study in algebraic geometry.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: I was under the impression that algebraic geometry related only to polynomials.  Do any results extend to arbitrary nonlinear systems?

Comment: Ok, that's fair. Still, making the jump from linear to polynomial equations already makes your question interesting, no?

Comment: Indeed it does, and I'm completely willing to accept that, for a completely arbitrary system of nonlinear equations this is an undecidable question

Comment: If you want to rule out examples such as $x^2+y^2=0$, you could restrict yourself to equations whose solution sets locally resemble $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$, I suppose...

Comment: Even then, although it takes three independent planes in $\Bbb{R}^3$ to intersect at a point, you can get a point as the intersection of just two algebraic surfaces in $\Bbb{R}^3$, such as $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=-x^2-y^2$...

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: good example, and I'd certainly consider that "nontrivial" (even though I could have defined that better...) That's interesting and unfortunate, since it means that the "easy" test doesn't really apply in general

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example take the equation
$$x^2+y^2=0$$
in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Interesting,  and as is always the case I didn't consider the trivial solution.   Are there nontrivial cases as well? (I'll edit the question accordingly)

Comment: Yes this is a clever solution, but is there a nontrivial solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-trivial"?